# Deserialization error in MEF due to missing assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, mef

I'm using MEF. I serialize one of the objects which relies on one of the loaded assemblies.

Now when I try to deserialize this object it throws "Unable to find assembly" exception. MEF loads the assemblies before this deserialization in another class (*I assume that the scope of this is application wide, it loads them into a public property*).

Since MEF has already loaded these assemblies to the application domain why `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize()` can't find them?

I can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load` but then what's the point of using MEF? Has MEF got special support for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now [assembly probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) did the trick, although I'm still not sure if this is the best practices because I still bypasses MEF in here which is no good.

*I'm still testing though to see if there is a side effect or something like that. Obvious disadvantage of these that I need to load same DLLs twice*